# How to check if my type t is surrounded by typing.List or not? For example check the difference between int and List[int]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pydantic

I want to execute different code depending on the type of my `t`.

I've got the follwing types:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    id: int
```

and

```
t1 = Person
t2 = List[Person]
```

now I want to check if my variable tX is if of a list type or a normal type. How can I do that?

```
def check_if_list(t):
    if type(t) == List:  # <- this doesn't work how can i do this check
        print('LIST') # some code
    else:
        print('NO LIST') # some code
```

`t1` and `t2` would give me:

```
check_if_list(t1)  # prints NO LIST
check_if_list(t2)  # prints LIST
```

Comment: `if isinstance(t, list)`

Comment: @Barmar Note that `isinstance` works with `typing.List` as well.

Comment: isinstance(int, list) and isinstance(List[int], list) returns false

Answer (score 0):

You don't to import the typing library. Just evaluate this type(t) == list.

Comment: `isinstance()` is better because it handles subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way of doing it is using the built-in function `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(t, list)
```

At least according to [`PEP-8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> *Object type comparisons should always use isinstance() instead of comparing types directly*

---

If you want to check an inheritance from `typing.List` you should be aware that a `list` doesn't come from `typing.List`, that's only a way of representing it in type hints.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I use typings.List therefore this doesn't work. I want to use typing.List instead of the normal list()

Comment: I edited my answer, you only have to switch list to List.

Comment: isinstance(List[int], List) returns false same as isinstance(int, List) therefore this doesn't work as my check

Comment: This returns true: isinstance(list(), List) but I use typings.List which is different

Comment: But List[int] isn't a variable, it's just a type hint, right?

Comment: that's right. however, in this case it's declared as variable

Comment: I don't think you can... this is my error when trying to initialize an instance of typing.List: TypeError: Type List cannot be instantiated; use list() instead

Comment: you might need pyton 3.9 not sure. I'm using 3.9. 
This works: from typing import List and then t = List[int]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241829/discussion-between-flak-zoso-and-danielmoessner).